# Why isn't my layer loading via pyqgis despite the file name and path being correct?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

I am writing up a python script on PyQGIS to load a point shapefile.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

src = "‪‪‪C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/pygis/Points.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(src,"Localities", "ogr")
if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"

else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Everytime I run this the "Layer failed to load!" message appears.

But checking the file name and path, well it appears to be correct.

[image]

What is the error that is causing the layer to fail to load?

Comment: Your code works fine for me and the layer loads.  Can you actually add the shapefile to QGIS manually? Do you have all of the required files that make up a "shapefile" (Points.shx and Points.dbf)  as well as Points.shp? (there are other optional files you may have, i.e .cpg, .prj, .sbn, etc... but they won't stop QGIS loading if they're not there)

Comment: It worked today. Was interesting that I got errors like above at the time.